# Is there a better way to find properties of object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-props, use-state

I am improving my coding skills. I wrote a code and it works fine. But I think it could be written better.

Here is are the codes and a bit of explanation,

I use the code below to `setState` for an array named transactions

```
useEffect(() => {
  TransactionService.getTransactions().then(data => {
    setTransactions(data.transactions);
  });
}, []);
```

I needed to sum an object in the transaction array so I wrote this code.

```
let a = transactions,
  total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  total += a[i].amount;

  console.log('total', total);
};
```

Then, use the code by calling it like this  {total}

```
<h1>{total}</h1>
```

Then I needed the value of a property in the last object within the array so I wrote this

```
var array1 = transactions;
var first = array1[array1.length - 1];

console.log(first);

const payment = { ...first };
```

And subsequently used it like this

```
<h1>{payment.amount}</h1>
```

The code works fine
Please any idea on how to write this better. Thanks

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unless you're mutating `payment`, spreading its content is useless. (here: `const payment ={...first}`)

Comment: I would use  a `.reduce` to get the sum and a `slice(-1)[0]` to get the last element in your array.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @EmileBergeron I did that because that was the only way I could access the value of amount which is inside first (the first object in the transaction array).

Comment: @AdeolaOni `first.amount` is the same as `({ ...first }).amount`, minus the unnecessary shallow copy, unless you're assigning something like `first.amount = 12` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works better for me. thanks,

```js
    
  const lastTransaction = transactions[transactions.length - 1];
  let lastPayment = ({ ...lastTransaction }).amount;
  const today = new Date();
  let lastMonth = today.getMonth() - 1;
  let relevantYear = today.getYear();
  let thisMonth = today.getMonth();

  const lastMonthTransactions = transactions.filter(i => {
  const date = new Date(i.date);
    return date.getMonth() === lastMonth && date.getYear() === relevantYear;
  }).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + parseFloat(curr.amount), 0)
```

@Tr1stan @Emile Bergeron